# Scanning Electron Microscope images of wheat grains

Tags: microscopy

I took SEM images of wheat grains but I see some granular particles on its surface and I don't understand what they are?
[image]
[image]
Is it some kind of deformation of the bran layer due to drying? Or is it the gold-palladium alloy coating which is done for SEM analysis of non-metals?